# Magento 2 receiving the error (300: AVS REJECTED No address or ZIP match only. CVV2/CVC2 match

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment-gateway, zipcode

We are using Magento 2.2.3 CE, when user trying to place an order with different billing and shipping addresses receiving the error (300: AVS REJECTED No address or ZIP match only. CVV2/CVC2 match.)

Could you please advise.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have enabled AVS(Address Verification System) in your payment solution. So double check your billing address. As AVS is enabled payment processor will verify your billing address with bank. Please check if the error does occur  when mismatch between shipping or billing address or the billing address is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Let me check and getback to you.

Comment: Hi @rajmohan the avs error getting at the time of when user trying to place an order with different billing and shipping addresses.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no error with the billing address. What payment method are you using. It will be more helpful if the payment log is enabled so we can check the exact request and responses

Comment: aps payment gateway. yes enabled debug log also but we didn't receive any error message.

Comment: So are you make using their official module or developed your own

Comment: official module only.

Comment: This error code states that Address doesn't match. CVV2, CVC2, and ZIP matches. So since you are not getting any log files try to troubleshoot in your network tab by checking the request parameters sent. Please also check for module configurations. Meanwhile also raise a support request to APS since they can check the request made

Comment: i have a one more doubt is it possible to provide different billing & shipping addresses while place an order with paypal express checkout? could you please advise.

Comment: Yes you can use different shipping and billing address. AVS will do a check with billing address only. It must match the address of the cardholder

Comment: but while place an order with paypal express checkout, shipping address only considering and reflecting to the billing address information in the order email & admin order details.

Comment: You will have a checkbox right to use billing address same as shipping address. If you uncheck it you will be having shipping and billing address different. Try using different billing address and see what happens

Comment: we have checked with the client regarding avs settings on payment portal but he is saying no settings found related to avs. and the issue which we are facing on production not in staging. and order status displaying as failed.

Comment: In this case it would be better to contact APS payment gateway support . Since we are not finding any logs they can check the request and response to find out the configuration in payment gateway which does validation to cause the issue

Comment: Yes @raj mohan thanks for you suggestion and help.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because of the following reasons. So kindly check your response code

https://prnt.sc/nik9cb

https://prnt.sc/nik9kf

Refer this link it will help you

http://www.emsecommerce.net/avs_cvv2_response_codes.htm

Comment: thanks for providing information will check and get back to you.